# Oracle Insert Value Into Middle of Existing Value

Tags: sql, oracle

This is similar to my previous question.  I have the following partial docket numbers:

```
docket_number
-------------
2012JV592
2016DR138
2018JV84
```

If the docket number is less than 10 digits, then I need to insert 0's after the second letter until the lenth is 10 digits.  Updated docket numbers would look like this.

```
docket_number
-------------
2012JV0592
2016DR0138
2018JV0084
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it the case that your docket_number should always follow the format 4 digits (year?) followed by 2 letters followed by 4 digits. Then simple sub-string of the docket_number and subsequent re-concatenation is sufficient.

```
select docket_number
     , substr(docket_number,1,6) || lpad(nvl(substr(docket_number,7),'0'),4,'0')  
  from test_dn 
 where length(docket_number) < 10
 order by docket_number;

and for update: 
update test_dn
   set docket_number = substr(docket_number,1,6) || lpad(nvl(substr(docket_number,7),'0'),4,'0')
 where length(docket_number) < 10;
```

If the format holds true then, depending on table size, this could be significantly faster as regular expressions are relative slow.

Answer (score 1):

One option might be to

- split docket_number into two parts: first part contains digits and letters, the second contains the trailing number
- result is concatenation of the first part and the second part left padded with zeroes up to total length of 10 characters

---

```
SQL> with test (docket_number) as
  2    (select '2012JV592' from dual union all
  3     select '2016DR138' from dual union all
  4     select '2018JV84'  from dual
  5    ),
  6  temp as
  7    (select docket_number,
  8         regexp_substr(docket_number, '[[:digit:]]+[[:alpha:]]+') part1,
  9         regexp_substr(docket_number, '[[:digit:]]+$') part2
 10     from test
 11    )
 12  select case when length(docket_number) < 10 then
 13              part1 || lpad(part2, 10 - length(part1), '0')
 14              else docket_number
 15         end result
 16  from temp;

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2012JV0592
2016DR0138
2018JV0084

SQL>
```

---

How to update rows in a table? By using such a `SELECT` in `UPDATE`, e.g.

```
SQL> select * from test;

DOCKET_NUM
----------
2012JV592
2016DR138
2018JV84

SQL> update test a set
  2    a.docket_number =
  3      (with temp as
  4        (select b.docket_number,
  5              regexp_substr(b.docket_number, '[[:digit:]]+[[:alpha:]]+') part1,
  6              regexp_substr(b.docket_number, '[[:digit:]]+$') part2
  7         from test b
  8        )
  9       select case when length(t.docket_number) < 10 then
 10                        t.part1 || lpad(t.part2, 10 - length(t.part1), '0')
 11              else docket_number
 12              end
 13       from temp t
 14       where t.docket_number = a.docket_number
 15      );

3 rows updated.

SQL> select * from test;

DOCKET_NUM
----------
2012JV0592
2016DR0138
2018JV0084

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks @littlefoot.  I have 35,000 rows of docket numbers.  How would I change this so the entire table is updated?

Comment: By converting it to UPDATE. Have a look at edited answer.

Comment: When I run this I get the following error: ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

Comment: It seems that there are duplicate DOCKET_NUMBERs. If so, modify line #9 to `select distinct case ...`

Answer (score 1):

You can split the data into three parts as digit group1, letters group, and digit group2 by using `regexp_substr()` functions, and `lpad()` function in order to add zeroes just before the second digit group, and then concatenate them directly by using `||` operators, assuming that you have the same data model for the whole table,

```
UPDATE t
   SET docket_number = regexp_substr(docket_number,'[[:digit:]]+')||
                       regexp_substr(docket_number,'[[:alpha:]]+')||
                       lpad('0',10-length(docket_number),'0')||
                       regexp_substr(docket_number,'[[:digit:]]+$')
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=5485be7399cbeb27320f4c1a274a9f18)</kbd>